# Split Included PDF Pages

Tags: graphics, pdfpages

I would like to create a single latex document which contains some text and some included PDFS, but so that the included pages look like they're a natural part of the document, ie. without unnecessary white space. At the moment I'm using \includepdf, which is fine except that it starts each included pdf on a new page.

What I'd like to do instead is to start the included pdf immediately wherever it appears, even if that's in the middle of the page, and then cut each page and split it so that part appears on the next page. I'm not concerned with where they're split. Obviously I'd also need latex to split every subsequent page in the PDF. I would then want latex to resume drawing immediately after the included pdf, which would again be part way down a page.

Is this possible?

Comment: No. LaTeX can't tailor PDF pages for you.

Comment: I doubt it's possible, because PDF files can be created in software other than LaTeX and for LaTeX to know how to split them seems like asking too much.

I think you're going to have to do it manually. If you have source .tex files, that's trivial, but if you only have PDFs, that's a lot of work.